# Create custom Popup in Ionic App

Tags: css, ionic-framework, popup

I try to create custom Popup in my Ionic App, I try to modify using Ionic CSS in to full fill my requirement but don't get success. Please help me or suggest me if any third party CSS available which i can edit and full fill my requirement.

**Proposed Design**

[image]

Comment: please share your code and what you have done so far, then others can help you. Otherwise, I just can offer you check this codepen and modify it according to your needs https://codepen.io/rdelafuente/pen/axeph

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ionic [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) it can be used to create custom popup along with custom template rather customizing `Alert Controller`. All you have to do is create a normal ionic page using `ionic generate page <pageName>` then using `ModalController` inflate the template and present the pop up to user. Read [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-modal-alert-with-html-form/47980/26) thread to create full flexed pop up that match up your requirement. [This](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-modal-alert-with-html-form/47980/38) is how you can add animation to models.

```
constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
}

let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Profile);
profileModal.present();
```