# Ionic Custom Popup

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, popup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc8Nr.png)
the character escape for new lines in the code is not working and the label for the input got lost somewhere... I'm not sure how I can create a custom popup window

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

      header: trip.name,

      subHeader: "Enter the number of slots\r\nPricing for the slots is " + trip.price + "\r\n" +

      "Slots remaining " + trip.slots + "\r\n"+ "Bookable slots " + (trip.slots*.1),

      inputs: [

        {

          label: 'Slots',

          name: 'Slots',

          placeholder: 'Slots',

          type: 'number',

          value: this.tripvalues,

          max: Math.trunc((trip.slots*.1)),

          min: 1

        }

      ],

      buttons: [

        {

          text: 'Cancel',

          role: 'cancel',

          handler: data => {

            console.log('Cancel clicked');

          }

        },

        {

          text: 'Login',

          handler: data => {

            

          }

        }

      ]

    });

    (await alert).present();

  }
```

Also how do I implement something like this??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhOkh.png)

Comment: have you try this one -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699581/11465205

Comment: I wanted to use an alert controller for this but seems that modal controller is the only way to go to get custom designs and form control